# Triviality of $d|n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

I am currently confused on a problem in a practice set I have been given. It reads the following:

> Let $d$ be a positive integer and let $n$ be an integer. Prove that $d | n$ if and only if in the unique expression $n = dq + r$ with $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq r < d$ the remainder is $r = 0$.

To me the question seems totally trivial in the sense that it follows from the definition of the notation $x|y$ that $y=m\bullet x$ for some $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ 
and in the other direction: if one assumes that $n=dq+r$ with $r=0$ then $q$ is by definition an integer such that $n$ can be expressed by the multiplication of $d$ (the divisor) and $q$ and so obviously $d|n$.

At first I thought this was asking to prove the existence of the division algorithm, but upon reflection it seems a totally different question. Could anyone provide some elucidation?

Comment: Does "the unique expression" mean that you already know from a prior result that the quotient and remainder are unique? Is that exactly what was written?

Comment: I don't think it is completely trivial. One direction is immediate from the definition of divisibility, but the other makes use of the uniqueness of the quotient and remainder in the division algorithm.

Comment: Is uniqueness necessary? If $d \mid n$ and we are given $n = dq + r$ with $0 \leq r < d$ then if $r > 0$ we have $n \equiv r \mbox{ mod } d$ which is a contradiction since $d \mid n$ implies $n \equiv 0 \mbox{ mod } d$.

Comment: The proof is so easy that we could consider it to be "trivial", but it is not an immediate consequence of the definition $d\mid n$ if and only if $n=kd$ with integer $k$. I think, in this case, it is a matter of taste.

Comment: @Riley You are essentially repeating the proof of the uniqueness of the remainder (which is not any simpler in this special case).